Blender 4.2: How to set rotation axis in Vertex Paint Mode
I am using Blender 4.2.0 and when I use Vertex Paint mode the mouse only rotates over the z-axis. How can I force Blender to use the rotation axis I want, inside Vertex Paint mode?
